# UITextField contentScaleFactor reset on focus

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, zooming

I think there is a glich with UITextField and contentScaleFactor. This is my scenario:

I have a UIScrollView which contains a UIView which contains many UILabels and UITextFields tiled in a grid. The UIView is set as the View to be zoomed on pinch by the scroll view. Scrolling and zooming works fine. When zooming ends, the contentScaleFactors for all the views are being updated in a recursive manner to make the text in the labels and textfields sharp. This works also. The problem is with UITextFields which, when tapped, they behave as magically reseting the contentScaleFactor back to 1. This can be observed only when the scrollview is zoomed in and tapping on a UITextField which has some text - the text suddenly becomes blurry. After the UITextField loses focus, the text still remains blurry.

After little debugging I discovered that UITextField has two subviews and that when focused the contentScaleFactor of the second subview only gets reset to 1. I managed to make the text sharp again after losing focus by manually changing the contentScaleFactor of the second subview to the scale of the scrollview, in the editingDidEnd delegate method.

Now the big question: How can I make the text sharp while editing it. I did try to set the contentScaleFactor after each change in the textfield but this doesn't work.

Comment: What iOS are you seeing this on? Can you provide a demo project?

Comment: tested with iOS 5.1 and 7.0. I cannot provide a demo project